# VB.Net WinForms - Databinding chart data in tab control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mqtt, plc

Okay,

Some background information:

I'm creating a Winforms app to talk to multiple devices over MQTT. These devices each have their own individual device name. My winforms app has an MQTT client, that upon receipt of an MQTT message from one of these devices, creates a tab. In that tab is a chart to display Key Process data for the device. This data is updated, periodically, on no particular time schedule. QoS is set to 0 (Fire & Forget).

Here is my theory of operation:

1. Message received over MQTT containing device name
2. Check through the tab control list, if that device name's tab does not exist, create it. Instantiate the chart control.
3. When a new messaged is received, and that device has a tab, then update the data in the pie-chart on that tab.

Using the below code, I am able to iterate through each tab-page, and through a watch-window I can verify that I am executing my delegated subroutine to update the tab control. However, I don't think that when I select "tempChart" as the chart control I want to databind, that I am actually databinding the correct chart.

Please feel free to bleed all over my code, as I am just a simple automation engineer, and NOT a developer.

```
    Private Sub UpdateKPITabs(ByVal tabbrowser As TabControl, ByVal name As String, ByVal tag As KPI)

    If tabbrowser.InvokeRequired Then
        tabbrowser.Invoke(New UpdateKPITabsDelegate(AddressOf UpdateKPITabs), New Object() {tabbrowser, name, tag})
    Else

        'Iterate through each tabpage and add an appropriately named chart, Textboxes, etc...
        Dim yValsHrsOvrall As Double()
        Dim xValsHrsOvrall As String()
        Dim yValsPctOvrall As Double()
        Dim xValsPctOvrall As String()
        Dim yValsPct As Double()
        Dim xValsPct As String()
        Dim yValsHrs As Double()
        Dim xValsHrs As String()

        yValsPctOvrall = {tag.UptimePct, tag.DowntimePct}
        yValsHrsOvrall = {tag.UptimeHrs, tag.DowntimeHrs}

        yValsPct = {tag.BreakPct, tag.BundlePct, tag.CoilChangePct, tag.EmergencyPct, tag.IdlePct, tag.MaintPct, tag.ShiftChangePct}
        yValsHrs = {tag.BreakHrs, tag.BundleHrs, tag.CoilChangeHrs, tag.EmergencyHrs, tag.IdleHrs, tag.MaintenanceHrs, tag.ShiftChangeHrs}

        xValsPct = {"Break %", "Bundle %", "Coil Change %", "Emergency %", "Idle %", "Maintenance %", "Shift Change %"}
        xValsHrs = {"Break Hours", "Bundle Hours", " Coil Change Hours", "Emergency Hours", "Idle Hours", "Maintenance Hours", "Shift Change Hours"}
        xValsPctOvrall = {"Uptime %", "Downtime %"}
        xValsHrsOvrall = {"Uptime Hours", "Downtime Hours"}

        For Each TP As TabPage In tabbrowser.TabPages

            Dim testChart As Chart = TP.Controls.Find(name, True).FirstOrDefault()

            If testChart IsNot Nothing Then
                If testChart.Name = name Then
                    SetupKpiDisplay(testChart, xValsPct, yValsPct)

                End If
            End If

        Next



    End If
End Sub
```

And setupKPIDisplay

```
    Public Sub SetupKpiDisplay(ByVal Chart As Chart, ByVal x As String(), ByVal y As Double())
    ' Populate series data
    If Chart.InvokeRequired Then
        Chart.Invoke(New UpdateChartDelegate(AddressOf SetupKpiDisplay), New Object() {Chart, x, y})
    Else
        Chart.Series("KPIData").Points.DataBindXY(x, y)
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```
    Private Delegate Sub UpdateChartDelegate(ByVal Chart As Chart, x As String(), y As Double())
```

Comment: If you are sure of the `name` passed into the `UpdateKPITabs` method an each chart has a unique name,  then there's no problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the code does not work, but does not throw any exceptions for me to debug with. I’ll have to do more testing Monday when I get back to my office.

Comment: Please check if chart has [SuppressExceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.suppressexceptions?view=netframework-4.8) property set to `false`. If it's true, some exceptions are newer thrown, which is sometimes good for production.

Comment: @Quirzo, Thanks for the info. I added that property to my list of properties to diddle upon instantiation and was still unsuccessful. I also did not have any exceptions come up. To verify the logic works, I repeated the test and successfully displayed the parsed text data into a textbox. So, I suspect my issue lies with the pie chart control itself. I will repeat the test with a different format of chart, or maybe a different charting plugin entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to ensure that I added a ChartArea to each Chart. I neglected to do this, and instead was only adding a chart series. My code works!

```
       With blankKpiChart
            .Name = "KPI" + name
            .Legends.Add(kpiLegend)
            .ChartAreas.Add(kpiArea)
            .Titles.Add(kpiTitle)
            .SuppressExceptions = "false"
            .Size = New Point(450, 450)
            .Location = New Point(10, 250)
            .Series.Add(kpiSeries)
        End With
```